# Mechanics predict an infinite number of bounces, does this make sense?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If we bounce a ball in ideal conditions, so after each bounce it retains only 1/4 of the original kinetic energy, then the time between bounces diminishes in half after each bounce. This will predict that the ball will be at rest at time=2, after  enduring an infinite number of bounces (a variation of the zeno paradox).

But contrary to zeno paradox, here the bounces can in principle be physically measured. If we limit our discussion to the newtonian framework, does it make sense that the ball will bounce an infinite number of times? or is this an example of the failure of Newtonian mechanics because it predicts infinities?

Comment: Maybe it’s a failure of the model to have enough detail to represent reality? The ball isn’t a point, the speed of sound in the ball isn’t infinite, etc.

Comment: @BobJacobsen what you said makes sense, but I was thinking ideal newtonian mechanics in which those issues should not appear. Let us say it is a point particle. Well, still the bouncing cannot happen at unlimited short times I guess

Comment: @BobJacobsen: That should be an answer.

Comment: if you assume "ideal conditions" in a "newtonian framework" what would cause   in each bounce to have the kinetic energy to be 1/4 of the previous one? Do you consider dissipation to be part of the ideal conditions within a newtonian framework?

Comment: @hyportnex yes, they are inelastic bounces

Comment: I think your example shows that inelastic bounces (dissipation) is *not* part of ideal conditions within the Newtonian framework, what ever that means.

Comment: @hyportnex that might be a good point, I will think more about it.

Comment: @hyportnex the bounce needs to take a finite amount of time to avoid infinite forces, so that would add to the total bouncing time. I am going to see if it makes sense to make those times shorter in the same way as before as the bounces get smaller. But again this makes no sense because the forces should increase unbounded as the bounces are smaller, so it will not work

Comment: I guess that is the answer

Comment: for a point ball on a perfectly smooth surface, there is no scale height. When would a bounce be too small to bounce again?

Comment: @JEB it will always bounce again, but the time added by the bouncing cannot diminish as t_i+1=t_i/2, so the bouncings will not end in a finite amount of time

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments of @hyportnex and Bob, I believe that the problem cannot be idealized properly without introducing inconsistent forces during the bouncing, that is, increased forces as the bounce becomes smaller. The question was motived by the thompson lamp supertask which some claimed to have solved by using and ball connecting circuits that require halving times between bounces.https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-supertasks/#MissLimiThomLamp

Comment: I do not believe that a *real* lamp behaves that way, you cannot turn off or turn on a *real* lamp within an infinitely short time, so the Zeno paradox cannot be applied that way. I am not sure about this and just thinking but this kind of paradoxes reminds me of the paradoxes one may get with singular perturbation where small quantitative changes create completely different qualitative changes in behavior.